# jQuery sortable() not firing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get the rows in a table to be sortable. When I make a toy example, it works fine, so the code seems good. My guess is that somehow in the much more complicated HTML of the real page, I'm not connecting my jQuery functions to the table body. This is what my DOM looks like. It's the `<tbody>` that I am trying to make sortable:

[image]

At the bottom of my `body` element, I have these lines:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#resources_table tbody').sortable();
    $('#resources_table tbody').disableSelection();
</script>
```

What do I need to do to connect the JS to the HTML elements, if that is actually what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: I realized that it is also important to note that the HTML for the table is generated dynamically via an AJAX call to a server. When that call returns, the table is created by updating the innerHTML of the div with the id "upload_res" with the string returned by the server.

Comment: try wrapping your script inside `$(function(){//add your script here });`

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked any console errors in browser. Can you reproduce it on JSFiddle?

Comment: Can you please share your html code and script on jsfiddle, let me look at it if I can reproduce it.

Comment: I would if I could, but it's not that easy. The actual html is generated at runtime from php scripts and mysql database queries. There are also other js and css files, so it's pretty complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73637/discussion-between-bhushan-kawadkar-and-randall).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this didn't fire is due to a race condition. The table is being loaded using the results of an asynchronous call to the server that returned *after* the `sortable()` and `disableSelection()` function calls occurred. To resolve it, I needed to move these two lines:

```
$('#resources_table tbody').sortable();
$('#resources_table tbody').disableSelection();
```

into the the AJAX block of code that runs after the `XMLHttpRequest` returned. That way, I could guarantee that the table had loaded before the function calls occurred.